# The time it takes to reach 63.2% of the maximum temperature inside the a box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, convection

This is for my undergraduate thesis. I think this is a combination of thermodynamics and calculus. This really troubled me for quite a while. So here's the problem.

Given:
 I have an incubator (box) with a volume of **1 m³**. The box is made of **plywood**.
 Initial temperature  = **84° F**.
 Power of the heat rod = **200 W.**

Question:
 **What time it takes to reach the temperature at 63.2% of maximum temperature using the heat rod?**

Please comment if I missed out any given or important information to solve this.

Comment: Your edits make it unanswerable (not that it was simple before).  An ideal insulator that doesn't allow heat to leave will have no maximum temperature.  In real life, the temperature will rise until the heat flow through the insulator equals the energy input (200W) or until the wiring/heating unit fails.

Comment: i edit it again. sorry.

Comment: You need the thermal conductivity of the walls.  The rate of heat transfer is roughly proportional to the temperature difference.  I think what you need to look at is Newton's Law of Cooling (which also works for heating :)   )

Comment: Can you just do an experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an object that is internally heated by a power source $P$ ($\mathrm{W}$), has a heat capacity $C$ ($\mathrm{J/K}$) and an outer surface area of $A$.

Assume it loses heat **by convection only** to the surrounding air at temperature $T_{\infty}$ and that the temperature of the object is uniform throughout (isothermal w.r.t. space), then the heat balance (conservation of energy) for an infinitesimal time $dt$ is, where $T$ is the object's uniform temperature:

$$P_{in}=P_{convection}+P_{stored}$$

Where $P_{convection}$ is given by Newton's cooling law, so we get:

$$P=hA(T-T_{\infty})+C\frac{dT}{dt}\tag{1}$$

Where $h$ is the *heat transfer coefficient*.

This differential equation is solved by separation of variables. Set $u=T-T_{\infty} \implies du=dT$, substitute into $(1)$:

$$P-hAu=C\frac{du}{dt}$$

Reworked:

$$\frac1C dt=\frac{du}{P-hAu}$$

Now integrate between suitable boundaries ($T=T_0, t=0$) and ($T=T(t), t$), where $T_0$ is the initial temperature of the object:

$$\frac1C t=-\frac{1}{hA}\ln\Bigg[\frac{P-hA(T(t)-T_{\infty})}{P-hA(T_0-T_{\infty})}\Bigg]\tag{2}$$

Now rework $(2)$ to make it explicit in $T(t)$. Then set $t=+\infty$ because that will give you the maximum temperature that can be achieved (thermal equilibrium, i.e. *steady state*), $T_{max}$.

Then use $(2)$ again to find the time to reach $T=0.632T_{max}$ and this will answer your question.

---

**Edit:**

$T_{max}$ can also be obtained as follows. At $t=+\infty$, $T=T_{max}$ and thus constant. This means that in $(1)$:

$$C\frac{dT}{dt}=0$$

So that:

$$P=hA(T_{max}-T_{\infty})$$

$T_{max}$ can easily be obtained from this. The result is the same as with the method above.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem, the A in the equation is the surface area of our incubator? or the heat rod?

Comment: And what is C?  the thermal capacitance of air?

Comment: something is wrong. because C = 1/hA in convective heat transfer but the equation 2 yields a strange unit which is not t in seconds.

Comment: Given, P in Watts, h in Watts/m².Kelvin,  A in m², T in K, and C is what? dimensionless?

Comment: $C$ is in $\mathrm{J/K}$. For a *homogeneous* object $C=mc_p$. For a composite or heterogeneous object: $C=\sum m_i c_{p,i}$.